# creating Email notification functionality in C# win app

Tags: c#, .net

Wonder if you can help please? I created an email notification system for windows app. This app is accessed via file server and citrix. It works perfectly using via file server and sends email notification using logged in users local outlook.

But when the user attempt to send notifications while accessing the same application via citrix it fails to run as we do not have the outlook access via citrix due to corporate policies.

We have been suggested to either request installation of outlook on citrix server (which will take a long time before it can be approved from top management) or re-write the code to access the local device outlook through citrix.

Does any one have any suggestion or example on how to proceed with such case?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Smtp mail client:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();    
message.To.Add("shiraz@address.com");    
message.Subject = "This is the Subject line";    
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("BSingh@address.com");    
message.Body = "This is the message body";    
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("**yoursmtphost**");    
smtp.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) for email notifications since [smtp client is obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

From MS site:

**Important**

We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use MailKit or other libraries instead. For more information, see SmtpClient shouldn't be used on GitHub.